# google app scripts Utilities.FormatDate malfunction

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In need to obtain a date in a integer format ddmmyyyy using as argument a cell that contains a date in standard google spreadsheet format.

**That's the code.**

```
function getDateToInt(date) {
  ddmmyyyy = Utilities.formatDate(date,SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetLocale(),'dd/MM/yyyy');
  var array = new Array();
  array = (ddmmyyyy.split('/'));
 return (parseInt(array[2])*100+parseInt(array[1]))*100+parseInt(array[0]);
}
```

**Here the problem:**

The function behave as expected in all case except when the month in the argument date is 8 or 9. In these cases returns #NUM!.

Any contribution is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using just a formula, the formula

```
=value(A1)
```

where a1 is a standard date such as 1/1/2016 with return "42370"

the number integer of the date.

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt()` uses 2 arguments, the variable to parse and the base.
The base is frequently omitted and assumed to be 10 but this is actually not ideal. Read [the doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/parseInt).

I guess that adding the base parameter will solve the issue you have but you can alternatively use the [Number()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp) function which will also convert the string into a number.